# Filling a portion of area between two functions

Tags: plotting, code-request, filling

How can I fill the portion of the area between the functions $f(x) = 2x + 4$ and $g(x) = -6x-1$ in the interval $[-1, 3]$? I have searched over here but there are mostly examples that do involve the usual normal distribution, or a single integrated function. Sometimes I wonder if it weren't ways simpler to use the most istintive code like that:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
plot1 = Plot[{2 x + 4, -6 x - 1}, {x, -2, 4}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"];
plot2 = Plot[{2 x + 4, -6 x - 1}, {x, -1, 3}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}];
Show[plot1, plot2]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try to learn as much as possible from you and from the Mathematica Guide.